# React Routing to Same Component with Different URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my main class I have a nav bar with the options below:

```
          <NavDropdown title="Search" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#/searchpage/p" onClick={this.dontEdit}>Find People</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#/searchpage/s" onClick={this.searchSchool}>Find Schools</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#/searchpage/w" onClick={this.dontEdit}>Find Work Places</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
```

These have a route which routes to the same component which then reads the parameter at the end of the URL and runs a different search depending on the value. For example 's' is search schools and 'p' is search people. If I navigate between the different search functions from the nav bar then it doesn't refresh to the new search. For example if I go from 'Find Schools' to 'Find Work' it stays on schools, but if I were to go direct to 'Find Work Places' then it goes there direct. Also if I navigate to the home page and back to another search then it works.

The route looks like:

```
<Route path="/searchpage/:type"  render={props => (<SearchPage {...props} findPerson={this.findPerson} routeReset={this.routeReset} getPersonsByName={this.getPersonsByName} />)}/>
```

Is anyone able to advise how to get this to route as I want it to? The search component is like:

```
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

import Flash from './components/flash';
import Search from "./components/search";

const searchtypes = {"p":"People","w":"Work Places","s":"Schools"};

class SearchPage extends Component {



  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      type:this.props.match.params.type
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <h4>Search {searchtypes[this.state.type]}</h4>
            <br/>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row><Col><Search {...this.props} type={this.state.type}/></Col></Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchPage;
```

Comment: Could you attach a link to a codesandbox? i'm not sure i'm entirely able to understand the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Route`'s `render` prop doesn't remount when the matched route doesn't change, i.e. even when the route matches but the route param is different it won't re-render. Instead use the `component` prop.

[react-router-dom component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component)

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
>   results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
>   mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
>   an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
>   children prop (below).

```
<Route
  path="/searchpage/:type"
  component={props => (
    <SearchPage
      {...props}
      findPerson={this.findPerson}
      routeReset={this.routeReset}
      getPersonsByName={this.getPersonsByName}
    />
  )}
/>
```

An alternative to this is to implement the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function in `SearchPage` to detect when the route param prop updates and update the type stored in state. This way the component won't continually unmount/mount each time.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.match.params.type !== this.props.match.params.type) {
    setState({
      type: this.props.match.params.type,
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I used the second solution using the life cycle method and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class SearchPage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <h4>Search {searchtypes[this.props.match.params.type]}</h4>
            <br/>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row><Col><Search {...this.props} type={this.props.match.params.type}/></Col></Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

The type data comes from props and therefore you should not persist it on the component state. 
**Note**: Make sure you use react-router Link component it seems you use native a tags